# Noninvertible matrix mod s from an invertible matrix

Tags: matrices, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $A\in M_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with nonzero determinant. Show that there exist infinitely many numbers $s\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$
> \exists a_s\in\mathbb{N}^*:A^{a_s}-I \equiv O\mod s.
> $$

My attempt is to use prove by contradiction. Suppose that for all $x$ in a finite set of natural number and for all $a\ne 0$ natural number, we have $$
A^a-I\not\equiv O \mod x \Leftrightarrow A^a\not\equiv I \mod x.
$$ 
Applying determinant to the above formula, we get that$$
a\det(A)\not\equiv 1 \mod x.
$$ So, we get that $x$ not devide $a\det(A)-1$ or, for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have $$
a\det(A)-1\ne kx,\quad \forall x\in\{x_1,...,x_l\} \text{ and } a\in\mathbb{N}^*.
$$
Moreover we get that$$
\det(A)\ne \frac{kx+1}{a},\quad \forall x\in\{x_1,...,x_l\} \text{ and } a\in\mathbb{N}^*.
$$ Then letting $a$ go to infinity, we obtain $$
\det(A)\ne 0,
$$ which not contradict the hypothesis.
Does this argument really can work? Does exists other path to get the claim in the conclusion? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I don't understand your proof. You start with a statement that is _not_ a negation of what you are trying to prove, then how can it be a proof by contradiction? Namely, you start with "For all $x$ in a finite subset of $\mathbb N$ …". But the true negation of what you want to prove is "For all but finitely many $s \in \mathbb N$, $A^a \not\equiv I \mod s$ for all $a \in \mathbb N^*$".

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

Let $\det A = d \ne 0$ (over $\mathbb Z$).

1. Are there infinitely many positive integers $s$ such that $d \not\equiv 0 \mod s$? Yes (justify, by specifying which values of $s$ guarantee this).
2. For which of these $s$ will $A \in M_2(\mathbb Z_s)$ be invertible? Are there infinitely many such $s$?
3. For such an $s$ as in Point 2, consider $A \in M_2(\mathbb Z_s)$. Since it is invertible, it belongs to the group of units of $M_2(\mathbb Z_s)$ [i.e., $GL_2(\mathbb Z_s)$]. What can be said about the order of this group? What does that imply about the order of $A$ (as a group element)?

Comment: I'll delete the comment then!

Comment: For the determinant to be a unit, nonzero modulo $s$ is not enough. It should be ”relatively prime to $s$”

Comment: @i707107 Of course, in mind I'd initially decided to argue only for prime $s$, but forgot that later on. Thanks!

Comment: @i707107 Edited the answer to reflect this (but still keeping it as a hint without giving it away).

Comment: In the last point, do you mean $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_s)$? The group $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is an infinite group.

Comment: @i707107 Oh indeed, that's a typo. Thanks!